# Some elements in the result of braycurtis dissimilarity matrix(numpy array) contains 'nan'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I calculated braycurtis dissimilarity matrix for the below matrix. Rows are communities ans columns are species

```
[[  0   0   0   0]
 [ 13 110   0   0]
 [  6   3   0   0]
 [  0   5   0   0]
 [  0 128   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [ 11  76  11   0]
 [  8  29   3   0]
 [  0  58   5   0]
 [  1   3   0   0]
 [  4  11   1   0]
 [  3  38   0   0]
 [  9  35   8   7]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [ 63 576  11   9]
 [ 24  99   0   0]
 [  1  29   5   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  2   0   0   0]
 [  1   4   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  8  20   0   0]
 [  3  21  13   6]
 [  1   4   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0]
 [  0   4   0   0]]
```

I used

```
dissimilarityMatrix=scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(CommGrouped, 'braycurtis')
```

and got the following result

```
[ 1.          1.          1.          1.                 nan  1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.                 nan
         nan  1.          1.          1.                 nan         nan
         nan         nan  1.          1.                 nan  1.          1.
  1.                 nan         nan  1.          0.86363636  0.921875
  0.12350598  1.          0.21266968  0.54601227  0.37634409  0.93700787
  0.78417266  0.5         0.51648352  1.          1.          0.68542199
  0.08943089  0.62025316  1.          1.          1.          1.          0.968
  0.921875    1.          0.62913907  0.71084337  0.921875    1.          1.
  0.93700787  0.57142857  0.95620438  1.          0.8317757   0.63265306
  0.91666667  0.38461538  0.44        0.76        0.73529412  1.          1.
  0.97305389  0.86363636  0.81818182  1.          1.          1.          1.
  0.63636364  0.42857143  1.          0.51351351  0.76923077  0.42857143
  1.          1.          0.53846154  0.92481203  1.          0.90291262
  0.77777778  0.85294118  0.33333333  0.52380952  0.7826087   0.84375     1.
  1.          0.98493976  0.921875    0.75        1.          1.          1.
  1.          1.          0.2         1.          0.6969697   0.79166667
  0.2         1.          1.          0.11111111  1.          0.32743363
  0.6547619   0.39267016  0.95454545  0.84722222  0.55029586  0.62566845
  1.          1.          0.6747141   0.21115538  0.64417178  1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          0.93984962  1.          0.74358974
  0.75438596  0.93984962  1.          1.          0.93939394  1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.                 nan
         nan  1.          1.          1.                 nan         nan
         nan         nan  1.          1.                 nan  1.          1.
  1.                 nan         nan  1.          0.42028986  0.2173913
  0.92156863  0.71929825  0.41007194  0.33757962  1.          1.
  0.74108322  0.21266968  0.47368421  1.          1.          1.          1.
  0.96        0.90291262  1.          0.55555556  0.5035461   0.90291262
  1.          1.          0.92156863  0.37864078  0.81818182  0.42857143
  0.20987654  0.19191919  1.          1.          0.88555079  0.54601227
  0.12        1.          1.          1.          1.          0.9047619
  0.77777778  1.          0.17647059  0.34939759  0.77777778  1.          1.
  0.81818182  0.91044776  0.69620253  0.26923077  0.3442623   1.          1.
  0.82548476  0.37634409  0.30612245  1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.          0.88235294  1.          0.56043956  0.50943396  0.88235294
  1.          1.          0.88059701  0.6         0.82222222  0.87301587
  1.          1.          0.98793363  0.93700787  0.79487179  1.          1.
  1.          1.          0.66666667  0.11111111  1.          0.75
  0.82978723  0.11111111  1.          1.          0.25        0.50877193
  0.57333333  1.          1.          0.95259259  0.78417266  0.49019608
  1.          1.          1.          1.          0.77777778  0.52380952
  1.          0.31818182  0.49152542  0.52380952  1.          1.          0.6
  0.24        1.          1.          0.88285714  0.5         0.21052632
  1.          1.          1.          1.          0.90697674  0.7826087   1.
  0.33333333  0.42857143  0.7826087   1.          1.          0.82222222
  1.          1.          0.8356546   0.51648352  0.25531915  1.          1.
  1.          1.          0.93442623  0.84375     1.          0.35632184
  0.25490196  0.84375     1.          1.          0.87301587         nan
  1.          1.          1.                 nan         nan         nan
         nan  1.          1.                 nan  1.          1.          1.
         nan         nan  1.          1.          1.          1.
         nan         nan         nan         nan  1.          1.
         nan  1.          1.          1.                 nan         nan
  1.          0.68542199  0.89913545  1.          1.          1.          1.
  0.99394856  0.98493976  1.          0.91848617  0.88319088  0.98493976
  1.          1.          0.98793363  0.62025316  1.          1.          1.
  1.          0.968       0.921875    1.          0.62913907  0.71084337
  0.921875    1.          1.          0.93700787  1.          1.          1.
  1.          0.94594595  0.75        1.          0.33333333  0.30769231
  0.75        1.          1.          0.79487179         nan         nan
         nan  1.          1.                 nan  1.          1.          1.
         nan         nan  1.                 nan         nan  1.          1.
         nan  1.          1.          1.                 nan         nan
  1.                 nan  1.          1.                 nan  1.          1.
  1.                 nan         nan  1.          1.          1.
         nan  1.          1.          1.                 nan         nan
  1.          0.71428571  1.          0.86666667  0.91111111  0.71428571
  1.          1.          1.          1.          0.6969697   0.79166667
  0.          1.          1.          0.11111111  1.          1.          1.
         nan         nan  1.          0.35211268  0.6969697   1.          1.
  0.75        0.79166667  1.          1.          0.82978723  1.          1.
  0.11111111         nan  1.          1.        ]
```

I'm not able to figure out if the result is correct and the reason for getting nan.

Please help!

Comment: Why are you using the Bray-Curtis distance, when it appears that you 1) don't know how to calculate and verify it, and 2) don't know why you get NaNs? If you use more exotic distance measures, you better find out how they work first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the output is correct.

It is easy to verify yourself: the [documentation on pdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) has the actual formulae for the Bray-Curtis distance:

> d(u, v) = Σ<sub>i</sub> (u<sub>i</sub> - v<sub>i</sub>) / Σ<sub>i</sub> (u<sub>i</sub> + v<sub>i</sub>)

So you could calculate all the distances yourself (or just a few to check).

The NaNs are then also immediately obvious: they are the result of the numerator and denominator both being 0, which happens for a bunch of vector combinations in your input.